# "Object Not Found" error while pullReplication in Couchbase mobile android

Tags: android, replication, couchbase

I have an Android application which does only pull replication from CouchDB. The code and replication was working fine for about 2 months and suddenly it stopped replicating and it gives following error in logcat,

```
E/RemoteRequest(17030): Got error status: 404 for myPath/DBName/_local/22ba996d673e136e09af3d780021718fda7a83c5.  Reason: Object Not Found
```

one more thing I noticed is `"22ba996d673e136e09af3d780021718fda7a83c5"` is `40-digit` while my actual document Ids consist of `32-digit`.

Any Idea what must be wrong here?

Comment: Your application is requesting a local document for replication. Local documents can not be replicated. More [information on the official guide](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/local.html).

Comment: like I mentioned, the same application was running fine for about 2 months. How come it suddenly change its behaviour?

Comment: Sorry I was not doubting you. Did your server had local documents before. Or did you just add them recently? Can you also give the logs on your server. It might help.